# Requests lib works in Window and times out in Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, proxy, python-requests

I have a simple python script to make a POST operation using requests lib. In windows, it works fine with no problem. In **Linux**, it's **not** working ***even though I can ping***. The script gives me in Linux:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 55, in <module>
    r = requests.post(urlPOST, json=payLoad, auth=('admin', 'pass'), verify=False)
  File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out'))
```

Again, ***I can ping*** the site *with no problems* in Linux.

***Questions:*** **1- What my be wrong?**
**2- Is there another way to check connection rather than ping?** I mean if it was a proxy problem, then I wouldn't be able to ping as well, right?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, the website is not responding to your request, and that's why you are getting a time out error. I will try to solve this by changing the user agent in the header, because some websites might be trying to avoid bots. Maybe try something like this:

```
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebK it/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.post(urlPOST, headers=header, json=payLoad, auth=('admin', 'pass'), verify=False)
```

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because it's responding in Windows with the exact same script

Comment: Did you try to request another website in linux?

Comment: No, that's I will try.

Comment: I tried with a different Linux and it's working. Looks like I have a problem with my image. I'll delete the question. But thanks anyway.